# How to handle Kinesis Data Stream without EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I want to handle my Kinesis streaming data without using EC2 instance?
Is there a possibility to accomplish this ie. through Lambda functions etc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Lambda service to process Kinesis streaming data. What you need to do is to create a Lambda function to process the data (the data will be available through `event`, first, parameter of the function).

In case of streaming data, your lambda function isn't invoked as a response to some event. Instead, Lambda service is periodically checking Kinesis for available data and then invokes your function.

For this to happen, you need to create event source mapping between your custom lambda function and Kinesis stream where you can also specify size of the batch that will be processed by lambda and its starting position.

Don't forget create proper role for your lambda function, it needs to have access to Kinesis service, so you need something like `AWSLambdaKinesisExecutionRole` permissions.

Another thing to consider is the batch size and how complicated your processing algorithm is. Lambda can run only for a limited time (currently 15 minutes is a maximum that you can specify), after that, it is automatically terminated by AWS. In such case, you will need to use something else than Lambda or split your lambda function into few smaller ones.

Comment: Thanks Matus for your reply. Yes I am aware of Lambda limitations
Few queries still on your reply
a) I am not clear on Starting position part of starting point in your reply

b) We need 2 Lambda here right? 1 for polling the source putting the data into stream and another for getting the data from stream

c) Do we need any checkpoint handling here as stream will contain data for 24 hrs min

d) Could you please clarify exactly how many Lambda functions needed here (Let's assume it is getting finished within 15 min)

Comment: You will need a producer(s) and consumer(s). While both of then can be lambda functions. Producers are usually applications that produce a lot of streaming data (clickstream from webpages, data from IoT sensors...). You don't need lambda function to send data to the stream. You can use `KPL` library and embed it in your application.

Comment: Batches that you are processing have sequence number. If you want to track the currently processed data then you can record the last sequence number of the batch.

Comment: Sure got it Matus but we want to avoid KPL to push data to Kinesis stream as it requires Java and Maven installation. We have a constraint to avoid using any VM. Is there any other way to push streaming data to Kinesis stream. Can any other AWS serverless service be leveraged?

Comment: If KPL is not an option for you then I would suggest looking at this https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation. It is not as powerful as KPL but it may suit your needs. But it needs to run lambda function to aggregate records. I don't think there is currently any other option for you to leverage. Unfortunately, working with Kinesis is mainly Java based.

Comment: Thanks Matus. Really appreciate. I am closing my question.